# How to install sbt on ubuntu/debian with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, sbt

The sbt installation directions indicate `sbt` were in the repository. However:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y sbt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sbt
```

Let us look around a bit ..

```
$ s apt-cache search sbt
coop-computing-tools - cooperative computing tools
libnet-z3950-simpleserver-perl - simple perl API for building Z39.50 servers
libusbtc08-1 - Hardware interface library for PicoTech USB TC08 Thermocouple sensor
libusbtc08-dev - Development files for PicoTech USB TC08
python-usbtc08 - Python wrapper for libusbtc08
s51dude - In-System Programmer for 8051 MCUs using usbtiny
```

Ummm .. *no ....*

So then is apt-get working with sbt on ubuntu?  Is there a special `apt repository` for it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After more searching the answer was found here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

This one does work

```
sbt
  Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...
```

And then.. be patient ..

Comment: I did all that, but in the end, when I say `aptitude install sbt` I get warning: Untrusted packages could compromise your system's security.
You should only proceed with the installation if you are certain that
this is what you want to do.

     sbt https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.13.deb

Do you want to ignore this warning and proceed anyway?
To continue, enter "yes"; to abort, enter "no":

Comment: `sudo apt-get install sbt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sbt
`

Answer (score 21):

Alternatively, you can also install it via:

```
export SBT_VERSION=1.5.5
curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v$SBT_VERSION/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip
unzip sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip -d ops
```

Please replace `1.5.5` above with the actual version of `sbt` you want.

Reference:

- https://medium.com/@yzhong.cs/getting-started-with-docker-scala-sbt-d91f8ac22f5f

Comment: sbt.dev is not a Debian format archive.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: @6005 Thanks for the comment, I updated the links. Would you mind trying again?