# sbt not found on ubuntu

Tags: scala, sbt

Hi I want to compile my application but I got this error

```
[Container] 2018/03/16 17:20:46 Running command chmod +x buildspec_build.sh && ./buildspec_build.sh
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.11 (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.11

==== local: tried
```

sbt installation looks like this in buildspec_install.sh

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
apt-get update
apt-get install sbt
```

what could be the issue? Thanks in advance

***UPDATE:***

Also displayed is this error:

```
:: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.11: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.11/sbt-0.13.11.pom
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install sbt on ubuntu/debian with apt-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529913/how-to-install-sbt-on-ubuntu-debian-with-apt-get)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I tried both mentioned ways ... but same issue

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I've updated my question

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805102/unresolved-dependency-org-scala-sbtsbt0-13-not-found-when-running-sbt-0-13

Comment: For the best chance of compatibility with current JDKs and such, you should also update your `project/build.properties` from 0.13.11 to 0.13.18. (And ideally eventually to the latest 1.x version, but getting on 0.13.18 would be a good start.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

full working solution is:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

echo "java installation ok"

# install sbt
echo "starting sbt installation"

apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823


apt-get update
apt-get install -y sbt
```

Answer (score 1):

***THIS ISSUE RESOLVE MY PROBLEME***

```
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo apt-key add
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

LINK SITE: https://www.scala-sbt.org/download/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).